# what is the difference of sequece of index in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am now using this command to select in MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT game_id
        FROM platform_reward_record
        WHERE hub_sync = 0
        GROUP BY game_id
        LIMIT 100
```

when I create index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `packet_db`.`platform_reward_record` 
ADD INDEX `idx_hubsync_gameid` (`game_id`, `hub_sync`);
```

the query is very slow, but using this index:

```
ALTER TABLE `packet_db`.`platform_reward_record` 
ADD INDEX `idx_hubsync_gameid` (`hub_sync`, `game_id`);
```

it is fast, why the field sequence affected whe slect speed? What should I learn from it?

Comment: The general rule (for the best index to fit a particular query) is to put the columns in the order `WHERE - GROUP BY - ORDER BY`

Comment: Any detail information？ @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: if you have many columns appearing in WHERE, then first the ones that are compared with the equality operator, then other (<, >, <>, LIKE) operators.

Comment: ok, thank you for give me this information. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: To understand why index-2 is better in your case than index-1, imagine that the `(game_id, hub_sync)` pairs are stored in sequential order. In index 1, you'll have: `(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,0), (2,1), (2,4), (3,1), (3,2), (3,7), (4,0), (7,0), (7,1)`. The rows with `hub_sync = 0` are not close together.

Comment: In index 2, you'll have: `(1,0), (2,0), (4,0), (7,0), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (7,1), (1,2), (3,2),(1,3), (2,4), (3,7)`. The rows with `hub_sync = 0` are close together and will require much fewer reads.

Comment: More discussion, including why to handle `WHERE` before `GROUP BY` and when it won't work:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of an index as an ordered data structure. Technically it's more than that, but when it comes to query optimisation, usually this is all you need to know.

To explain why this matters in your case, I'll use a common analogy: a phonebook. A phonebook is a dataset ordered by (surname, name), so it's actually an index made of paper.

Because it's ordered, looking for Tom Baker is reasonably fast. Finding all Bakers would also be reasonably fast (unless they're thousands... but that's because you're a human, not a machine). Finding all Toms would be impossible. Or better said, it's possible, but you have to scan ALL entries from the beginning to the end. It's slow, it's like not using an index at all. If the index were ordered by (name, surname), you could find all the Toms but not all the Bakers, and you'd still be able to find Tom Baker.

So now you should understand why, in general, the order of columns of an index matters. But let's see why it matters **in your case**.

You want to restrict your search to a certain hub_sync, and then group the rows by game_id. In this order! The opposite wouldn't work: once you grouped the rows you lose the hub_sync information.

So first you apply the `WHERE`, and you need to use the first row of the index for that (remember: you can quickly find the Bakers, not the Toms). Then you can group the rows by the second row of the index.

As a side note, you can use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`. It's not faster, but it makes it more clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

An Index is a way of getting to a specific record more quickly.

Consider this [slightly unrealistic] Address table:

```
select * from addresses ; 
+------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| id   | Country | State    | City        | Local_Address      |
+------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
|    1 | USA     | Alabama  | Birmingham  | 12345 Long Street  | 
|   22 | USA     | Arkansas | Little Rock | 2345 Middling Road | 
|  333 | USA     | Arizona  | Phoenix     | Short Street       | 
|  777 | UK      | B1       | Birmingham  | 12345 Long Street  | 
| 8888 | UK      | W1       | London      | 1 Pall Mall        | 
+------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Let's assume that there's a covering index on all the important fields:

```
create index ix_covering on addresses( country, state, city, local_address );
```

Now, if we want to find addresses in country='USA', the index is *very helpful*, because it "bunches" them all together and the database can quickly skim through that part of the index.

Now, what it we want to find all the addresses in "Birmingham"?

The index is of *no use* to us, because the entries for 'Birmingham' are scattered all over the index.  There is *no benefit* using the index, because you'd have to read the whole thing to make sure you got *all* the 'Birmingham's.  You might as well read the original Table, and that's exactly the database does.